# mathematica browser function in excel is empty

Tags: excellink

I have installed mathematica version 10.4.1.0 (64bit) on Windows 10 and Link for Excel version 3.7.1
Unfortunately I am not able to select any mathematica functions from the browser that I open in excel. The table is empty. [image]
Has anyone had a similar problem? How could this be fixed?
Thanks,
Andrzej

Comment: Do you have access to a later version of Mathematica? It works for me, with Mathematica 11.3, and the same version of Link for Excel (3.7.1).

Comment: No, I don't. Maybe I will have to upgrade.

Comment: It turns out I had 32bit Office installed. I changed that to 64bit and it works!